# Simple Method to refresh Viewmodel with KnockoutJS using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a simple viewmodel that has a ko.computed method. This ko.computed methoud has multiple ajax call with in it. I would just like to call the ko.computed method from an anchor tag to refresh my data set.

My ViewModel:

```
var MyDataViewModel = {
     Date: ko.observable(FormatDate()),
     Receiving: ko.observableArray(),
     Triage: ko.observableArray(),
     Technician: ko.observableArray(),
     Scrap: ko.observableArray(),
     Refurb: ko.observableArray(),
     CA: ko.observableArray(),
     Dispatch: ko.observableArray()
}

MyDataViewModel.Refresh = ko.computed(function () {
   var self = MyDataViewModel;
       //AJAX CALLS HERE
    });
```

My anchor tag:

```
<a href="#Refresh" data-bind="click: Refresh" ><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
```

When I click the anchor tag, I get the following message:

***Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.***

Any suggestions assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `MyDataViewModel.Refresh` should be a function and not a computed: 'MyDataViewModel.Refresh = function () {
        var self = MyDataViewModel;
         //AJAX CALLS HERE
    };'

Comment: @nemesv Post as answer :) you sit are a gentlemen and a scholor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) needs a function which is executed when you click, so you don't need a `ko.computed` here just a `function`:

```
MyDataViewModel.Refresh = function () {
        var self = MyDataViewModel;
         //AJAX CALLS HERE
};
```

You only need to use `ko.computed` when you want to calculate new values from your existing observable properties. From the computed observable [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

> What if you’ve got an observable for firstName, and another for
>   lastName, and you want to display the full name? That’s where computed
>   observables come in - these are functions that are dependent on one or
>   more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of
>   these dependencies change.